# Views navigation with Xamarin.forms MasterDetail page and caliburn.micro

Tags: xamarin.forms, caliburn.micro

I want to implement a menu using a masterdetail page with caliburn.micro, but the only documentation i managed to find is [this](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/master-detail-forms).

I know I have to use a NavigationPage inside `MasterDetailPage.Detail` and load my views into that, but I can't find any example of how MasterDetails composition works and how can I navigate from view to view (for example, for prism there's [this](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms,%20which%20is%20pretty%20enlightening)).

Any help would be appreciated.